# asp.net multiview issue with Safari

Tags: asp.net, safari

I have a very simple page built in asp.net (.NET Framework 4) which has a multiview containing a few views that are displayed as a button is clicked - this seems to work fine on all browsers I have tested with on my local machine but as soon as I move it to the server, the active view doesn't change when the button is clicked when viewing the page with Safari.

I don't see any errors or warnings when debugging (or when viewing the page on another browser on the server).  Interestingly, the page displays and works fine on the server if i view it with my iPhone(4S) but trying to browse it using Safari 5.1.2 installed on my PC is where I am seeing the problem.

The code that doesn't appear to be firing is as simple as below and fires on an asp button click:

```
MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2
```

Has anyone encountered any similar issues as I haven't been able to find anything much online?

The page in question can be seen at the following URL - http://www.ddlgroup.eu/ArdbegSurvey/survey.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I do not - if this had been the issue wouldn't I have expected to see it on my local machine too when debugging?

Comment: I do not know but on my safari it works, is throw me one other error...on the end of the survey.

Comment: Yes the error at the end of the survey is expected as i have put it on current server to test - when moved to the production server it will write results to a text file (very antiquated I know but that is what the boss wants!) what version of Safari are you using?

Comment: safari version = the same as you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to stem from accessing the site using Safari through the main business proxy - I don't understand exactly how this could have been an issue but changing to use a different proxy seemed to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I have check the page and what I think you need to do is to disable any possible cache on browser because the page name is not change from page to page and from post back to post back, and this maybe the problem. Add all this parameters on PageLoad and try again.

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-4));
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
Response.Expires = 0;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

In my safari same version is worked fine - some other error appear on the end of survey.

Comment: I've added your code but still encountering the same error - when I get home I'll try accessing via Safari on a machine outwith the network since you are able to access it OK just to try and rule out some kind of weird network issue.

Comment: @allanmayberry88 a firewall issue maybe ? Anyway is working on me

Comment: Yes, was an issue with my proxy, changed to a different one and it worked OK - I'll add an answer once SO lets me :)